# cannot cast to java.lang.Comparable

Tags: java, binary-tree, classcastexception, tree-traversal

Although this question has already been asked but I have an implementation specific doubt.

I am trying to print the top view of the binary tree and following is the complete code for it:

```
import java.util.*;

class Node{
    int data;
    Node right;
    Node left;
    Node(int data){
        this.data = data;
    }
}

class Pair<F,S>{
    private F first;
    private S second;
    public Pair(F first, S second){
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
    
    public F getFirst(){return first;}
    public S getSecond(){return second;}
}

class BinaryTreeTopView{

    public static void printTopView(Node root){

        if(root == null)
            return;

    Queue <Pair<Node,Integer>> q = new Queue<>();
    Map <Integer,Node> map = new HashMap<>();
    Pair<Node,Integer> p = new Pair<>(root, 0);
    q.add(p);
    
    /*
    I am storing nodes and the corresponding horizontal distances 
    in the form of a pair which then are being stored in the queue
    to ensure level order traversal
    */

    while(!q.isEmpty()){
        Pair<Node,Integer> temp = q.peek();
        q.remove();

        if(map.containsKey(temp.getSecond())==true){
            map.put(temp.getSecond(),temp.getFirst());
        } else {
            System.out.println(temp.getFirst().data);
            map.put(temp.getSecond(),temp.getFirst());                
        }

        if(temp.getFirst().left!=null){
            Pair<Node,Integer> left = new Pair<>(temp.getFirst().left, temp.getSecond()-1);
            q.add(left);
        }
        
        if(temp.getFirst().right!=null){
            Pair<Node,Integer> right = new Pair<> (temp.getFirst().right, temp.getSecond()+1);
            q.add(right);
        }
        
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Node root = new Node(1);
    root.left = new Node(2);
    root.right = new Node(3);
    root.left.right = new Node(5);
    root.left.left = new Node(4);
    root.right.left = new Node(6);
    root.right.right = new Node(7);
    root.right.left.right = new Node(8);
    root.right.right.left = new Node(10);
    root.right.right.right = new Node(9);
    root.right.right.left.right = new Node(11);
    root.right.right.left.right.right = new Node(12);
    
    printTopView(root);
}
}
```

It compiles fine but an exception is being raised at the runtime.
Now I have been getting the following exception and I am unable to figure out what the problem is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
Pair cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable at  java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUpComparable(PriorityQueue.java:652)
at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUp(PriorityQueue.java:647)
at java.util.PriorityQueue.offer(PriorityQueue.java:344)
at java.util.PriorityQueue.add(PriorityQueue.java:321)
```

Comment: What is the **complete** stack trace?  i.e. which line in your code does it correspond to?

Comment: Also, I don't believe this is your real code, as `new Queue<>()` doesn't compile.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth..Oh i'm sorry...But it is my code....I actually posted the unedited code...Of course it won't compile...bt the one i actually comiled had PriorityQueue...
So...
Anyways thanx for pointing that out!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's because Pair isn't implementing Comparable. Either implement it:

```
public class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> {
    public int compareTo(Pair o) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or use Comparator in Your priority queue

Using Comparator ;

```
PriorityQueue<DummyObject> pq = new
             PriorityQueue<DummyObject>(5, new DummyObjectComparator());
```

Define your Comparator :

```
class DummyObjectComparator implements Comparator<DummyObject>{

      // Overriding compare()method of Comparator 

       public int compare(DummyObject s1, DummyObject s2) {
                   //some code
       }
 }
```

Comment: Ok that worked!
Thanx a lot for the answer!
But i still am not clear about why do i need to implement comparable interface and override compareTo method!

Comment: From error it seems you are using priority queue ,If you see this class use comparable or if comparator to compare between two element

Comment: Yeah but what is the need of using a comparator when i am not using it....I all i am doing is storing my objects in a queue...??

Comment: Would you give example of "Or use Comparator in Your priority queue"?

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to add `Pair` instances to a `PriorityQueue`, so your `Pair` class must be `Comparable`. A reasonable implementation could be to force `F` and `S` to be `Comparable` on their own right, and then compare by the first element, and then the second one:

```
class Pair<F extends Comparable<F>, S extends Comparable<S>>
    implements Comparable<Pair<F, S>> {

    // All the code you already have is fine

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pair<F, S> o) {
        int retVal = getFirst().compareTo(o.getFirst());
        if (retVal != 0) {
            return retVal;
        }
        return getSecond().compareTo(o.getSecond());
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok..but i still have got one dout..my method is not making any comparsions anywhere so why do i  need to compare o.first and o.second

Comment: The `PriorityQueue` sorts its elements  by their natural order (i.e., it sorts them). In order to accomplish that, the elements must be comparable.

Answer (score -1):

Your statement:

```
Queue <Pair<Node,Integer>> q = new Queue<>();
```

Doesn't compile because `Queue` is an interface and cannot be instantiated. I suspect that you've used a `PriorityQueue` instead.

Do you really need a priority queue, or would a simple `LinkedList` would suit your algoritm?

UPDATE:

BTW, with a `LinkedList`, the output is:

1
2
3
4
7
9