# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: proj.Car cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Tags: java, treemap

I'm trying create something like [this](https://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/implement-graph-using-map-java/) tutorial on creating a graph and I'm coming across an error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: proj.Car cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable`.

Car class

```
 Integer id;
 String model;
 String brand;
 float price;
```

Cars class (both have been instantiated already):

```
TreeMap<Integer, Car> m;
TreeMap<Car, LinkedList<Car>> adjList;
```

Main:

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Car> entry : a.m.entrySet()){
             Car val = entry.getValue();
             LinkedList<Car> list = new LinkedList<Car>();
             a.adjList.put(val, list);
}
```

This creates an `adjList` for every Car object in `m` but the problem is the error. I've tried making sure the entered variables are of the same type by using `instanceof` and it returns true. So i'm not sure where the error comes from.

Comment: Car implement Comparable..... please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44355842/cannot-cast-to-java-lang-comparable

Comment: does your Car class implement the Comparable interface?

Comment: @rr11 Can you post the definition of `Car`

Answer (score 2):

TreeMap is a SortedMap implementation and it requires its keys to implement the Comparable interface in order to sort the keys.

So I assume Car does not implement Comparable. If you add this implementation, you'll be fine.